# programming wrt cloud computing

Tags: cloud

I have been wondering over this question for a while. I have read up stuff about cloud computing(and there has been an unusual hype these days). I have understood the theory behind, how using a cloud can help me use my resources efficiently and blah blah blah. So my question is how to use(if we can) this technology in our programs? For example, with multi-core processors dominating the market, we know our programs should support multithreading(and probably should not crash when porting from single-threaded processor to multi-threaded one). So Is there any such programming paradigm we should be following or is the cloud concept completely aloof from our programs written in object-oriented and procedural languages??

Answer (score 0):

Cloud computing platforms should be nearly transparent to the applications they host. There should be no need for a particular programming paradigm for cloud computing in most cases.

The cloud platform you use should be capable of providing all the services and dependencies required by your application. There are cloud platforms for most major web development frameworks. This means you can use whatever framework/paradigm best meets your projects needs without worrying much about what the cloud API needs.

If you are developing in PHP, Rails, Sinatra, Java, Node.js, Grails, Groovy, and other open frameworks look at [Cloud Foundry](http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/post/4613634293/explaining-the-magic-triangle)

For .net take a look at [Windows Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/)

In both of these cloud platforms the developer experience actually made simpler.